# Excel - Add/Append content from one cell to new column

Tags: excel

I have two lists in SheetX and SheetY. From these two I wish to create a new list in SheetZ.

Problem I have is that I don't want to add all values from SheetX and SheetY but combine specific parts of each.

For insteand:
SheetX:A1:A10,SheetX:A15,SheetX:A20:A23 (14 Cells)
SheetY:A4:A10,SheetY:A12,SheetY:A15:A25 (17 Cells)

Should result in SheetZ:A1:A31

The lists are quite long (500 rows or more) and would be nice to be able to just mark them and have it linked with SheetZ: column A: and add on to it when I go through the lists.

Ofc I can just ctrl+click and copy but would rather have it variable if I need to add more sheets in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal do this is with a VBA macro. Sticking to just the functions in Excel would be a massive drain on resources.
If your data is in A:A then add 'x' in the B:B column next to the records you want carried over on SheetZ.

In VBA (Alt+F11) insert a module and add the code below

```
Sub Macro1()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'

Dim wsX As Worksheet: Set wsX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetX")  
Dim wsY As Worksheet: Set wsY = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetY")  
Dim wsZ As Worksheet: Set wsZ = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetZ")  

Dim i As Integer: i = 2 ''Row number on the data sheet
Dim z As Integer: z = 2 'Row number on the combined sheet

With wsX
  Do While IsEmpty(wsX.Cells(i, 1)) = False ''Assumes the data is uninterrupted
    If UCase(wsX.Cells(i, 2)) = "X" Then ''The "2" assumes the x will be in column 2
      wsZ.Cells(z, 1) = wsX.Cells(i, 1)
      z = z + 1
    End If
  i = i + 1
  Loop
End With

i = 2  ''reset the row to start at the top of the next worksheet
With wsY
  Do While IsEmpty(wsY.Cells(i, 1)) = False
    If UCase(wsY.Cells(i, 2)) = "X" Then
      wsZ.Cells(z, 1) = wsY.Cells(i, 1)
      z = z + 1
    End If
  i = i + 1
  Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: My knowledge in VBA is quite limited, but as far as I can tell from reading your code. Wouldn't that macro take everything from SheetX and SheetY and combine it to a list in SheetZ?

Comment: I've tested and it works. Translation: `Do While IsEmpty(wsX.Cells(i, 1)) = False` go down the A column row by row until you hit a blank, `If UCase(wsX.Cells(i, 2)) = "X" Then `  If there is a "X" in the B column of that row `wsZ.Cells(z, 1) = wsX.Cells(i, 1)` copy that column A value into SheetZ